# Why do vampires ever use cars, even during emergency situations?

Tags: vampire, the-vampire-diaries

Without a doubt, vampires can run faster than any car on Earth. But still they use cars during emergency situations when comfort has a low priority. Why?

Comment: I've never read TVD, so this is a comment rather than an answer. In some vampire storylines, using *any* supernatural ability (rapid healing from a gunshot, say) uses up some of their stored energy/life force/blood. If it's an emergency, a vamp might *need* that stored energy for something else - like fighting (or healing, etc). Better to burn up some gasoline and save the more valuable resource.

Comment: @JohnC You're projecting emergency situation on vampires (During such situations, they really run away by own). Look at this: Vampire's GF has been kidnapped & she may be killed anytime.

Comment: Sachin Shekhar, and yet, in the checkmarked answer, vamps are worried about looking *conspicuous* - either running at 60 mph, or carrying multiple people. Must not be much of an emergency... :) As to the kidnap scenario, what if the kidnappers are *stronger* than the vamp? He might need a little extra stored energy. It's a risk either way.

Comment: @JohnC Such energy problem is never presented in TVM.. Vampires don't run out of energy in a small event. The big problem --for example-- is here: Vampire is not allowed in home.. So, a human faculty can help to force home owner for it..

Comment: If you want to Ask about The Vampire Diaries, why not say so in your exposition, if not directly in your Question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Out-of-universe, cars are easy, look good, require little to no post-production effects to pull off, and can pull off some cool moves in-frame. Cars also allow for relatively easy exposition or dialogue scenes as the actors don't have to mime running while not showing exertion and while having a normal-volume conversation.

In-universe, cars are less conspicuous than someone running at highway speeds, they can be used to transport humans in a slightly more protective shell than simply being carried (and so as a corollary look less ridiculous than an actor loaded down with more then one human), and they require less mental and physical exertion by the vampire; while a vampire CAN run, they may need some or all of their faculties for other things.